# how to display moving points on a map from a database

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, latitude-longitude, google-earth

There are logs where it is indicated: board number, time, date, latitude and longitude.  information about their movement is constantly updated and new boards appear.  how to display their movement on the map?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

To display markers on a map, you can perhaps use [Leafletjs](https://leafletjs.com/) for Javascript.

It is useful library that allows you to use a large array of mapping basemaps, and plot overlays on it, such as adding markers based on latitude or longitude, or drawing polygons or shapes. You can also overlay multiple maps, and there is a lot of functionality linked to the elements.

See their [tutorials](https://leafletjs.com/examples.html) to get started or reference the [documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html) to see how you can manipulate the markers on a map.